# Consultar dados de 1 dia á 3 dias atrás mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando demostrar registros dos últimos 3 dias atrás, porém deve ser subtraído dois dias e apenas demostrar o valor de um único dia que antecede os 2 dias, atualmente tenho o seguinte código que é demostrado o valor do último mês subtraindo o mês atual.

```
ProdValor  | Data
250,00     | 01/04/15
150,00     | 02/04/15
50,00      | 03/04/15
```

Código:

```
 $busca = mysql_connect("$local","$usuario","$senha") or die("ERRO AO CONECTAR AO MYSQL, VERIFIQUE COM O ADMINISTRADOR" . mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("$banco") or die("BASE DE DADOS INVÁLIDO");
 $pesquisa = mysql_query("SELECT sum(ProdValor) FROM vendas WHERE MONTH(data) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH))");


 while($sum = mysql_fetch_array($pesquisa)){
    $soma2 = $sum['sum(ProdValor)'];
 }    

 echo $soma2;
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione na pergunta um exemplo de retorno que você espera. Confesso que achei a pergunta bem confusa.

Comment: Essa frase não está nada clara: "[...] porém deve ser subtraído dois dias e apenas demostrar o valor de um único dia que antecede os 2 dias [...]". Procure melhorar a explicação, senão dificilmente alguém conseguirá te ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar de algumas maneiras, dentre elas:

- Passando a data que você quer por parâmetro direto pelo PHP:

  ```
  $pesquisa = mysql_query("SELECT sum(ProdValor) FROM vendas WHERE data = '".date('Y-m-d')."'");

  $pesquisa = mysql_query("SELECT sum(ProdValor) FROM vendas WHERE data = '".$data."'");
  ```
- Subtraindo a quantidade de dias desejada:

  ```
  $pesquisa = mysql_query("SELECT sum(ProdValor) FROM vendas WHERE data = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 DAY)");
  ```

Espero que ajude

Abraço

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porém do modo exemplificado é demostrado todos os dados á 3 dias atrás, o que gostaria é o valor de um apenas um determinado dia há 3 dias atrás, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho certeza se entendi direito, mas pelo que entendi a *query* abaixo pega as 3 ultimas datas e você pode determinar qual data retornar dentro desses 3 dias.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY v.DATA DESC) n, v.* FROM vendas v) T
WHERE T.N <= 3
AND T.DATA = $data
```

Espero tê-lo ajudado
Abs

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   SUM(PRODVALOR) AS TOTAL,
   DATA
WHERE
   DATA BETWEEN DATE_ADD(DATA, INTERVAL - 3 DAY) AND NOW()
ORDER BY
   DATA ASC
LIMIT 1
```

O `NOW()` é o dia atual.

Nessa consulta, é selecionado o primeiro registro de três dias atrás.